# Rattle loads titanic_train full data but fails when subsetted

Tags: r, rattle

I can load the titanic_train dataset into Rattle with no problem, but if I subset a few columns I get the error:

`Error in paste(., collapse=""): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Here's my work flow:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rattle)
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)

dat <- titanic_train
df <- dat[c(2, 3, 5, 6)]
df %<>% mutate_at(c("Survived", "Sex"), factor)
rattle()
```

Both *dat* and *df* show up as class data.frame.

Rattle loads *dat* correctly, but fails with the error code when I try to load *df*.

What am I missing?

**Update**

Now I'm more confused. The following code works with the *dat2* data frame, but I get the error when trying to load *df* in Rattle as an R Dataset. (I updated *mutate_at* to *mutate(across* but it made no difference.

```
library(titanic)
library(magrittr)
library(rattle)
library(dplyr)

dat <- titanic_train

dat2 <- dat[c(2,3,5,6)]
df <- dat[c(2,3,5,6)]

dat2 %<>% mutate(across(c("Survived","Sex"), factor))
df %<>% mutate(across(c("Survived","Sex"), factor))

rattle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Rattle is seeing the *df* object as the stats package call to the `df` function for the F distribution. The same error occurs when naming the object *dt* in the code above -- Rattle fails because (I think) it considers *dt* the T distribution function. Changing the object name to *dt1* or *df1* works just fine in Rattle.

This wasn't noticeable when I tried `class(df)` or `typeof(df)`. While it's dangerous to name objects with existing function/object names, *df* for data frame and *dt* for data table are commonly seen.

Comment: Solved the issue of getting a dataframe into Rattle when the dataframe was called "data" as well. Simply renamed to "data2" and it worked fine. Legend!